# NSMutableArray: data missing when init with an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, init

As the screenshot showing, anyone who knows what's the problem of it? Thanks for kindly help!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it didn't run on for loop after you stop it on breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you for look just put `codeList` and your problem will be fixed.
check this I modified your method.

```
-(NSArray *) checkVisibleCode:(NSArray *) codeList{
    NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:codeList];
    for (NSString *code in codeList) {
        if (![self.codeMapping.allKeys containsObject:code]) {
            [list removeObject:code];
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing object from the Array you're iterating on.
It's a bad practice that can lead to mistakes like this.

You simply have to replace

```
for (NSString *code in list)
```

with :

```
for (NSString *code in codeList)
```

Comment: Not just bad practice, but illegal practice that gets punished with a crash if the operating system notices it.

Comment: Thanks for you guys' help, it's my mistake. BTW, before today the code almost run passed in 1 month, I don't know why it only failed today, how to deal it?

Comment: You simply must do a copy of your array. Iterate on the first one, and remove objects from the second. This way you'll be sure that you have iterate on all elements.
Then just keep the second array for your use.
Replace `list` with `codeList` in the for loop condition.

Comment: Yes, I've fixed it as @bmindhacker 's code, it's same as ur said. BTW, also thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score -1):

Don't delete objets from an array or dictionary or any collection set while you're iterating on it .
Keep the indexes you want to delete when iterating then remove all the objets. You can use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` method :

```
NSMutableArray * list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:codeList];

NSIndexSet * indexesToRemove = [list indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *code, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [self.codeMapping.allKeys containsObject:code];
}];

[list removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToRemove];
```

Comment: @Azevedo thanks for ur help, but this block looks worked not good for me, it has blocked long time for my app...

Answer (score -1):

You should do this using indexesOfObjectsPassingTest and objectsAtIndexes: Even if you follow for example Anbu's reply to make your code work, this code runs in O (n^2). Do it with a list of 100,000 objects where every second object gets removed, and your app dies a sad death because it runs out of CPU time.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it as @bmindhacker 's code, it works well.